# Eliminar un cliente por rut y que se borre en

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf, visual-studio-2017

tengo la siguiente interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde tengo el siguiente código para agregar al cliente:

```
      public bool AgregarCliente()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            using (var bd = new OnBreakEntities())
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                cliente.RutCliente = txtRut.Text;
                cliente.RazonSocial = txtRazonSocial.Text;
                cliente.NombreContacto = txtNombreContacto.Text;
                cliente.MailContacto = txtMailContacto.Text;
                cliente.Direccion = txtDireccion.Text;
                cliente.Telefono = txtTelefono.Text;
                cliente.IdActividadEmpresa = IdActividadEmpresa();
                cliente.IdTipoEmpresa = IdTipoEmpresa();
                bd.Cliente.Add(cliente);
                bd.SaveChanges();
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            flag = false;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

El cual si me funciona, pero el que no logro hacer ni encontrar es el de eliminar al cliente el cual intente con el siguiente codigo y algunos mas pero ninguno me ha funcionado.

```
     public void EliminarCliente()
    {
        using (var bd = new OnBreakEntities())
        {

            var client = bd.Cliente.Any(c => c.RutCliente == txtRut.Text);
            if (client)
            {
                bd.Cliente.Remove(client);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te falta grabar el cambio

Comment: Graba el cambio y compara strings con Equals.. solo por buenas prácticas

Comment: @RamiroBarone El problema es que cuando hago eso me dice en el bd.Client.remove(client) - me dice que el argumento 1 no se puede convertir de bool a OnBreak.bd.cliente

Comment: Es, porque Any te devuelve un booleano, con ese metodo estas preguntando si existe alguno, entonces si existe es true, sino es false. Deberias usar FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta grabar el cambio.

```
public void EliminarCliente()
{
    using (var bd = new OnBreakEntities())
    {

        var client = bd.Cliente.where(c => c.RutCliente == txtRut.Text).FirstOrDefault();
        if (client != null)
        {
            bd.Cliente.Remove(client);
            bd.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```